# Unity 2D - How to I connect one point to another with a line in code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I want to make a line which stretches from a starting point to a end point, so I have a point which has a random position and another point at 0, 0 I want a line to connect them how would I do that? I have tried nothing so far because I don't know what to use. I would also like to be able to change the texture line or a custom line. I want to do this all in 2D and in unity c#

Comment: Should I use a line renderer and if so how do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Line Renderer Component attached to some gameobject, then you assign the desired material and you can via code specify the positions of the points:

```
LineRenderer lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
Vector3[] positions = {Vector3.zero, someOtherVector3};
lineRenderer.SetPositions(positions);
```

Note: you can use as many points as you need.
Note 2: No matter that your game is 2D, you can use Vector3, just keep in mind that the z is 0.